Which Test to Find a Correlation Between Two Selections.
I have a dataset of about 22 000 items, from which two processes have selected a small subset. I want to know if there is a correlation between the two selections, and I wonder which statistical test to use.
The problem is both selectors only pick a very small subset of items.  22026 items are selected by neither, 350 by selectorA only, 44 by selectorB only, and 3 items are selected by both selectors. Contingency table below:
Contingency Table:



selectorA
0
1




SelectorB   0
22026
350


SelectorB   1
44
3



I tried the Chi-square test, and I got a Chi-value over 4, and for other selectors it goes over 3000! I think the fact that there are so many (0,0) pairs in the table gives too much weight to the unselected items. Am I doing it right? Is there a better test to use?  My background isn’t in stat.

Could you provide more context to the question? What are the column labels, are the numbers means, etc.

Using R (including Yates' continuity correction), I got $\chi^2 \approx 4.26$ and $p \approx 0.039$ so I would guess your calculation may be sensible.  You might then decide from this $p$-value to reject a hypothesis that the two selectors are independent (and then see that the data suggests some positive correlation).  Fisher's test might lead you to a similar conclusion.  The large number not selected by either is not a particular difficulty; the small number selected by both is more interesting - if it had been $2$ rather than $3$ you might have come to a different conclusion.
